# text-overflow: ellipsis and display table-cell

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an CSS-Table (width 100%) with 2 columns. The first column has a fixed width (for example 180px) the second column should fill the rest of the width.

Inside the second column, there is a long text (inside a `<p>`-Tag). Now I want to use `text-overflow: ellipsis` to crop the text to one row and the text should be as long as the available space.

Thats what I ve tried:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-i">
            ABCD
        </div>
        <div class="card-r">
            <strong>Some title</strong><br>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS code:

```
// This container is just for testing
.container {
    width: 400px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.card {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

.card-i, .card-r {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.card-i {
    width: 180px;
}
.card-r {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

p {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    word-break: break-all;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

table formating display let basicly element to shrink/expand according to te content it holds, so `height` and `width` works like `min-height` and `min-width`.

`table-layout:fixed;` can force `width` on such `display` to act as `width`,  `height` will keep expand anyhow.

```css
.container {
    width: 400px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.card {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
  table-layout:fixed;
}

.card-i, .card-r {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.card-i {
    width: 180px;
}
.card-r {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

p {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    word-break: break-all;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-i">
            ABCD
        </div>
        <div class="card-r">
            <strong>Some title</strong><br>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Thats so simple, but I didn't knew the table-layout:fixed; command!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `card-r` doesn't have any width constraint.  For `text-overflow: ellipsis` to work there **must be a width consstraint on the container**

Rather than setting `card-i` to `display: table-cell` try setting both `card-i` and `card-r` to `display: block` and using `calc` to calculate the width the right div needs to be.  Then the text-overflow should work.

```
.card-i, .card-r {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.card-i {
    width: 180px;
}
.card-r {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 15px;
    width: calc(100% - 214px);
}
```

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qa7ju8c3/1/)

Comment: But calc isn't supported by IE8 (ok, thats not that big problem), but there is as well, no support for Android 4.1, 4.3 and only partial support by 4.4 and IE9 (see http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)